# Type mismatch in ADODB.Parameters while rounding up the values before insert

Tags: vba, stored-procedures

I am trying to round of value while executing stored procedure from vba code and I get type mismatch error for this below code snippet.

```
     Dim counter as Integer
     Set param = objMyCmd.CreateParameter("@ABC", adDecimal, adParamInput)
     param.Precision = 10
     param.NumericScale = 5
     param.Value = .Cells(2, counter)
     objMyCmd.Parameters.Append Round((param), 2)
     counter = counter + 1


     Table: [ABC] [decimal](10, 5) NULL,

     SP:     @ABC decimal(10,5) = NULL,
```

I changed numeric to decimal. I got the precision value correctly inputed but I still get "Application uses a value for the wrong type" error .

Any suggestions on how would I round of the value while inserting into SQL Server tables?

Comment: at this time, what is the value of counter and the cell trying to round?  Could try converting before rounding.

Comment: Either `counter` is not numeric or `.Cells(2, counter)` (which likely returns range object, not just cell value) cannot be directly passed to `Round()`. PS - this is not sql server question, vba only.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav the value of the counter is 6, (6th column)

Comment: I am trying to insert 14.23232323232 as 14.23. Earlier I used this -             If .Cells(iRowNo, 6) = "" Then ABC = 0 Else ABC = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(.Cells(iRowNo, 6), 2)                        which worked fine in vba. But when I modified it to be used as inserting through stored procedure , it gives me error

Comment: The parameter type will need to match the data type, so I'd suggest checking the cell contents then if numeric `paramValue=cdbl(.cells(2,counter))` then `round(paramValue,2)`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav  'Set param = objMyCmd.CreateParameter("@ABC", adNumeric,         adParamInput)
            param.Precision = 18
         param.NumericScale = 2
         param.Value = CDbl(.Cells(2, counter))
         objMyCmd.Parameters.Append Round(param, 2)
         counter = counter + 1'                                                                        This still gives Type mismatch error

Comment: can you show table?  should this be a `adDouble` in the type in create param?

Comment: I changed to decimal instead of numeric. I see that it is now picking up the precision value correctly but still not rounding up the answer